# How to add checkbox array to zip file for download from a form

Tags: php

I am trying to get a foreach loop to give me the checkbox values (which have the file names for values) from my form, to be added to a zip file.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="download[0]" value="Fact_Sheet_1.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[1]" value="Fact_Sheet_2.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[2]" value="Fact_Sheet_3.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[3]" value="Fact_Sheet_4.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[4]" value="Fact_Sheet_5.pdf" />
```

Works fine if I click on one checkbox but when I tick more than one checkbox only one file gets added to the zip file.

My code is below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
    foreach ($_POST['download'] as $key => $val) {
        $filename = 'Fact_Sheets/' . $val;
        }
    }
system("zip -r files/zipfile  $filename");
```

Comment: This is very dangerous, as somebody can directly issue system commands via `$_POST['download']`.

Comment: @nickb Ok I haven't made it more secure for the moment just trying to get the functionality working for now. Please elaborate.

Comment: Might want to verify that the filenames that are passed back are valid to the ones you are allowing to be selected

Comment: @Grant: No, design something without a gaping flaw, _then_ get _its_ functionality working. You're programming the wrong way around.

Comment: @laurence Burke - They are, well the first one is, thereafter only one gets written.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit - Please explain

Comment: If somebody posted something like `" && rm -rf /"`, `rm` would be recursively invoked to delete files starting at the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST['download'] as $key => $val) {
    $filename = 'Fact_Sheets/' . $val;
}
system("zip -r files/zipfile  $filename");
```

You overwrite `$filename` each time.

Instead, build it up:

```
$filenames = '';
foreach ($_POST['download'] as $key => $val) {
    $filenames .= '"Fact_Sheets/' . $val . '" ';
}
system("zip -r files/zipfile  $filenames");
```

(Also note that it's conventional to name the `input`s like `"download[]"`, so that the indexing is done automatically for you. This is not crucial, though.)

---

But **don't do this**. As discussed in comments, it has a ***GAPING FLAW***. Don't write this code, even if you're "just testing", or even if you'll "fix it later". Don't let it ever exist in the first place, or you *will* make a mistake, or accidentally leave it in place, or not find the time to do it properly.

<sup>I considered *not encouraging you* by not writing this answer, but concluded that if I allowed some other answer to be accepted, it might be a dangerous answer that'd make things even worse.</sup>

Comment: "I see the light!" - will amend my ways.

Comment: Thanks v much, I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: I finally settled on this solution using [PCLZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/), works great:  foreach ( $pdfArray as $key => $val) {
     $filename .= $val . ',';
     }

 define('PCLZIP_SEPARATOR', ',');
 
 require_once('includes/pclzip.lib.php');
 $archive = new PclZip($archiveName);
 $list = $archive->add( rtrim($filename, ",") );

Comment: @Grant: Please use backticks to delimit code, so that it is legible. Also, if you came up with your own solution, _write an answer_. And yea, that looks very good :)

Answer (score 3):

At first you're using `$filename =` instead of `$filename .=` (and variable name should be `$filenames`) .)

Than you're not checking whether file exists and doesn't contain invalid characters I may spoof request and send to you: `download[8]=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

So your entire code should look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $filenames = array();
    foreach ($_POST['download'] as $key => $val) {
        if( basename( $val) != $val){
          throw new Exception( 'Hacker attempt!');
        }
        $filename = 'Fact_Sheets/' . $val;
        if( !file_exists( $filename)){
          throw new Exception( 'Invalid file!');
        }

        $filenames[] = escapeshellarg( $filename);
    }

    if( count( $filenames)){
         system("zip -r files/zipfile " . implode( ' ', $filenames)); 
    }
}
```

Yes, that's right you should use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) too.
Imagine:

```
download[8]=`rm -rf *`
```

And why aren't you using [php zip library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a bad person, I'd try (at least) to send him: `\`reboot\`` or `\`rm -rf *\`` :)

Comment: "And why aren't you using php zip library?" - fair enough.

Comment: @Grant most of your problems would be solved by using that library and executing shell command from webscript is dangerous practice even if you're aware of all the risks.

Comment: @Vyktor - "executing shell command from webscript is dangerous" - Got it! Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Change you code to this one:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="Fact_Sheet_1.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="Fact_Sheet_2.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="Fact_Sheet_3.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="Fact_Sheet_4.pdf" />
<input type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="Fact_Sheet_5.pdf" />
```

Comment: He's still overwriting the `$filename` variable.